# Run 'if url contains' conditional function without page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, if-statement, single-page-application

I have a single page app where part of the url changes but the page does not refresh.

I have a simple function that needs to run, only when 'foo' appaers in the URL.

This obviously does not work because it only runs the first time the page loads, and 'foo' may not be there yet.

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf("foo") > -1) {
//stuff
}
```

Is there a way I can detect a URL change in order to run my function?  Or a better way?  The URLs in question do not contain a hash, so hashchange isn't working.

Comment: you can watch the route change event if you use some kind of route

Answer (score 0):

You could use a while loop that runs till it finds what you need like this:

```
var found =false;
while(found == false){

    if (window.location.href.indexOf("foo") > -1) {
    //stuff
        found = true;
        //more code 
     }

}
```